# Add text before last matched occurrence of search word in a file

Tags: text-processing, awk, sed

I need to add a few lines of text before the last occurrence of a word (SearchWord in my example) in multiple files.

- search should be case insensitive.
- the word is present in multiple lines of the file.

**Existing Data in a file**

```
SearchWord abc defgh
SEARCHWORD abc1234
sEarchWord abcd
sometext 1
sometext 2
```

**Required Output**

```
SearchWord abc defgh
SEARCHWORD abc1234 
NEWLINE_1_ADDED
NEWLINE_2_ADDED
NEWLINE_3_ADDED
sEarchWord abcd
sometext 1
sometext 2
```

Comment: The keyword `SEARCHWORD` only occurs once in your data...

Comment: @don_crissti Then my question would be whether the keyword should be matched case-sensitively or not, and if not, could there still be multiple matches?

Comment: @don_crissti Of course (leaving `sed` aside), but we still don't know where the extra data should come from...

Comment: SeachWord should not be case sensitive. This searchword present in multiple lines in a file. But New text should be added before last matched searchword

Comment: @don_crissti : No we don't have those 3 lines in any file

Comment: @zanna : It's case insensitive search and insert lines before last match only.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Use `ex`, the POSIX file editor

`ex` is the non-visual form of the `vi` file editor.  It actually predates `vi`.  `vi` (and Vim) still use `ex` commands; any time you type a colon and enter a command, that is an `ex` command (though Vim has many custom extensions).

Since `ex` opens the *whole* file for reading, rather than operating in a stream, addressing can work backwards as well as forwards, unlike in Sed or Awk.

For this particular edit, use the following one liner:

```
printf '%s\n' 'set ignorecase' '$+?searchword?i' 'NEWLINE_1_ADDED' 'NEWLINE_2_ADDED' 'NEWLINE_3_ADDED' . x | ex input.txt
```

To test the command (print to standard output rather than saving to file), use `%p` rather than `x` as the final command:

```
printf '%s\n' 'set ignorecase' '$+?searchword?i' 'NEWLINE_1_ADDED' 'NEWLINE_2_ADDED' 'NEWLINE_3_ADDED' . %p | ex input.txt
```

To handle multiple files:

```
for f in *.txt; do
    printf '%s\n' 'set ignorecase' '$+?searchword?i' 'NEWLINE_1_ADDED' 'NEWLINE_2_ADDED' 'NEWLINE_3_ADDED' . x | ex "$f"
done
```

---

### Explanation

Running the `printf` command by itself, you can see the commands which are passed to `ex`:

```
set ignorecase
$+?searchword?i
NEWLINE_1_ADDED
NEWLINE_2_ADDED
NEWLINE_3_ADDED
.
x
```

The `set` command is self-explanatory.

`$+` refers to the line *after* the last line, and `?...?` means to search backward from there.  (The `+` makes it so a file with a matching last line will be handled correctly.)  `i` means to "insert" text *before* the line found.

The `.` on a line by itself ends the text to be inserted.

`x` saves and exits.

Comment: Thank you @wildcard..This solution perfectly works for all files in a folder and saving the file after changes.

Answer (score 2):

If you have `tac` and GNU `sed` you could use

```
$ tac file | sed '0,/searchword/I s/.*searchword.*/&\nNEWLINE_3_ADDED\nNEWLINE_2_ADDED\nNEWLINE_1_ADDED/I' | tac
SearchWord abc defgh
SEARCHWORD abc1234
NEWLINE_1_ADDED
NEWLINE_2_ADDED
NEWLINE_3_ADDED
sEarchWord abcd
sometext 1
sometext 2
```

#### Explanation

- `tac` print out the file backwards
- `0,/pattern/` operate on first occurence of pattern only
- `I` case insensitive search
- `s/old/new/` replace `old` with `new`
- `.*searchword.*` match the whole line containing `searchword`
- `&` the whole matched pattern in replacement
- `\n` newline

Maybe more readable:

```
tac file | sed '0,/searchword/I s/.*searchword.*/&\
NEWLINE_ADDED_3\
NEWLINE_ADDED-2\
NEWLINE_ADDED_1/I' | tac
```

Answer (score 2):

Easier if you saved those lines in a text file, e.g. `infile` then used `ed` to edit your files in-place:

```
for f in ./*.txt; do
ed -s "$f" <<\IN
.t.
?[kK][eE][yY][wW][oO][rR][dD]?-1 r infile
$d
w
q
IN
done
```

If you just wanted to insert some text (not the content of a file), it's similar:

```
for f in ./*.txt; do
ed -s "$f" <<\IN
.t.
?[kK][eE][yY][wW][oO][rR][dD]?-1 s/$\
some_text\
more_text\
last\\_\&_line
$d
w
q
IN
```

Replace `w` with `,p` to see what it does without modifying the files.
Note that backslashes, ampersands and delimiters have to be escaped in the RHS of a substitution. The same applies to newlines, except the last one.
How it works ? Well, duplicate the last line, search for your keyword backwards, insert the text or the content of the file before that line, delete the duplicated last line, write, quit.

---

Sure, if you don't need to edit those files in place and just want to print the modified versions, like *Zanna* does, you don't need arcane text editors with a syntax from another age... You can do it with a single `sed` invocation - and because *Wildcard* kindly reminded me that in this family of editors there's a dedicated command to `i`nsert text before a match let's use that and some branching:

```
sed -s '1{h;$!d;b end
}
/keyword/I{H;$!d
}
//{x;p;$!d
}
:end
${x;/keyword/Ii\
some_text_here\
more_text_here\
and_a\\_backslash
}' ./*.txt
```

This only works with `gnu sed` though... with other `sed`s you'll have to run a loop (this time without the branch part so as to have a blank line between each file content):

```
for f in ./*.txt; do
sed -s '/[kK][eE][yY][wW][oO][rR][dD]/{H;$!d
}
//{x;p;$!d
}
${x;/[kK][eE][yY][wW][oO][rR][dD]/i\
some_text_here\
more_text_here\
and_a\\_backslash
}' "$f"
done
```

As you can see even with `i`nsert, one still have to escape backslashes and newlines (except the last one). Other than that, it's simple: it just accumulates lines in the hold buffer and exchanges when encountering a match; on last line it exchanges again and inserts the text before the match, if any.

Comment: [`ex` is *much* simpler.](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/338954/135943)  Although I see that [`ed` has the "insert" command also](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/ed.html#tag_20_38_13_14).  Using the `s` command here makes things more complicated than `insert`, because it requires special character escaping.  (Why not just use "insert"?)  Also, does `ed` not have the compound address feature that I use in my `ex` answer (`$+?regex?i`)?

Comment: @Wildcard - why not use `i`nsert... well, that's a good question buddy... This may sound really retarded but... I don't have an answer :)